# Create data in data with Chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I created a simple Pie chart with Chartjs. Is it possible to create data inside the data itself? I know there is a way to create multiple datasets, but this creates another pie outside the main pie.

Here is an example: [image: pie chart]

Lets say 'hoofdgerecht' is a total of 50%, but there are still other properties inside hoofdgerecht itself, and these consist of 5% 10% and 20%. How can you achieve this?

I tried:

```
Data:{
labels: ['hoofdgerecht',
data:{ 
labels: ['warm', 'koud']
```

]
};

UPDATE: My code

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("voedselVoorraad").getContext('2d');
var voedselVoorraad = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Hoofdgerecht", "Nagerecht", "Bijgerecht", "Zout", "Suiker", "Peper"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Voedsel op voorraad',
            data: [35, 32, 29, 30, 28, 14],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider all of them as same data set items, But you can group the related ones with the same color. You can even add different labels for them also.

You might have used a different approach but idea can be the same. If you can just paste the actual code you used to draw the chart you have now.

Refer : https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html

```
var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [45, 25, 20, 10],
        backgroundColor: [
            pattern.draw('square', '#ff6384'),
            pattern.draw('circle', '#36a2eb'),
            pattern.draw('diamond', '#cc65fe'),
            pattern.draw('triangle', '#ffce56'),
        ]
    }],
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Yellow']
};
```

Lets say you can divide the `45` to 3 sections, What you can do is,

```
var chartData = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [20, 10, 15, 25, 20, 10],
        backgroundColor: [
            pattern.draw('square', '#ff6384'),
            pattern.draw('square', '#ff6384'),
            pattern.draw('square', '#ff6384'),
            pattern.draw('circle', '#36a2eb'),
            pattern.draw('diamond', '#cc65fe'),
            pattern.draw('triangle', '#ffce56'),
        ]
    }],
    labels: ['Red','Red','Red', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Yellow']
};
```

In your case you have to dynamically update the dataset to include all values as dataset items and you then have to change the backgroud-color and boarder-color arrays accordingly.

For an example let's say you had an initial dataset like below,

```
data: [35, 32, 29, 30, 28, 14];
labels: ["Hoofdgerecht", "Nagerecht", "Bijgerecht", "Zout", "Suiker", "Peper"]
```

Now just assume that you can divide this `35` in the `Hoofdgerecht` for more sub sets like `10`,`5`,`20`. The idea is to add them to the original data set like the other normal values.

```
data: [10, 5, 20, 32, 29, 30, 28, 14];
labels: ["Hoofdgerecht_1", "Hoofdgerecht_2", "Hoofdgerecht_3", "Nagerecht", "Bijgerecht", "Zout", "Suiker", "Peper"]
```

Comment: @Blank In your case you have to dynamically update the dataset to include all values as dataset items and you then have to change the backgroud-color and boarder-color arrays accordingly.

Comment: Im totally new to this, can you please provide more information? I tried copying and pasting your code but that does not work (Of course it wont but I dont know other ways)

Comment: You obviously  don't going to hard code the values right ? How do you going to do that ? I'm talking about `data: [35, 32, 29, 30, 28, 14]` , how do you get the values ? Can you paste the actual business code you are going to write.

Comment: There are no official data, it's for a schoolproject and the data values are not static I can use any data I want, the chart is important not the data